# Is there a way to get banner output either in xml or any other format?

Tags: android, admob

Does anybody know how to get AdMob banner output in xml/JSON format rather than HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AdMob serves you an ad containing HTML inside of a WebView. You don't have control over this content, and it's going to be HTML anyways. So no, this isn't available with the AdMob SDK.